# How to tag people on facebook photos?

Tags: javascript, facebook-apps

We have developed an app that creates a jpg of five friends as a result. We need the app to tag the people in the photo, but is not working. The code seems to be valid as we don't get any errors.

```
var tagdata= new Array;

tag1['tag_uid'] =Lamigos[0];
tag1['x'] =41;
tag1['y'] =373;

tag2['tag_uid'] =Lamigos[1];
tag2['x'] =172;
tag2['y'] =373;

tag3['tag_uid'] =Lamigos[2];
tag3['x'] =302;
tag3['y'] =373;

tag4['tag_uid'] =Lamigos[3];
tag4['x'] =100;
tag4['y'] =436;

tag5['tag_uid'] =Lamigos[4];
tag5['x'] =100;
tag5['y'] =567;


tag['data']=tagdata;
tagdata[0]=tag1;
tagdata[1]=tag2;
tagdata[2]=tag3;
tagdata[3]=tag4;
tagdata[4]=tag5;


   FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
    message:'Ahora puedes...',
    url:"http://www.xxxxxxx.com"+imgfin,
    tags:tag
   }, function(response){

      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error al compartir tu lista');
      } else {
        vercapas(6);
  document.getElementById("simgfin").src=imgfin;
  document.getElementById("botcompartir").innerHTML="<a name='fb_share' type='button_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.xxxxxxxx.com" + imgfin + "&t=Estos son mis patas más patas'>Compartir</a>";
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos does not say that a `tags` parameter is accepted when posting to /me/photos.

I guess you have to add the tags *after* you posted the photo - see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So we would have to ask permission again to add the tags right?

Comment: Not necessarily “again”, but rather together with the other permission necessary for the post in the first place …